# Is it possible to cut an mp3 file without re-encoding it?

Tags: editing, daw, mp3, cutting, cut

I have some mp3 files that need to be cut in segments (one mp3 file for the start, one separate mp3 file for the middle, and another mp3 file for the end). It can be easily done in any DAW, but DAWs tipically transform the file into a lossless format, then apply all new edits, to then re-encode back to mp3 during export. This process degrades the file twice, once for each mp3 encoding, so I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Is there a way to cut an mp3 file into time segments (different mp3 files), without having to re-encode the data in the process?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. I've used [MP3 Trimmer](http://www.deepniner.net/mp3trimmer/) which does this. However, the result was unplayable in some programs (no audio after the first point in the file I edited), so I ended up reencoding anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try MP3 Direct Cut:

https://mpesch3.de/
or
https://download.cnet.com/MP3DirectCut/3000-2169_4-10068315.html